# The web.app page isn’t working

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

When i try to open `web.app` it doesnt work. But `vagrant up` running successfully. Hier is my Homestead.yarn file

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/www/
  to: /home/vagrant/www

sites:
    - map: web.app
  to: /home/vagrant/www/web

databases:
    - homestead
```

I'm using Mac OS. 
laravel box : laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 1.1.0)
in hosts 127.0.0.1 web.app (192.168.10.10 and 127.0.0.1 both doesn't work)
vagrant and homestead are up to date. Any idea?
`web.app:8000` doesn't work else

Comment: Have you added the entry to your Mac's `/etc/hosts` file?

Comment: why do you use vagrant? try using laravel Valet

Comment: @JRLambert yes i have added.

Comment: @SandipPatel because i can't. It is from job.

Comment: your host must have `192.168.10.10 web.app` is everything started in your VM  ? if you ssh into your VM (`vagrant ssh`) can you run `curl http://web.app`

Comment: @FrédéricHenri yes it gives 403 forbidden

Comment: ok so you first need to fix this - your server does not start, review the webserver logs

Comment: @FrédéricHenri in vagrant show that webserver is working

Comment: how can it show it is working ? you cannot access from host neither from the VM - the server can be started, does not mean all process are running correctly

Comment: @FrédéricHenri oh thats true. but how where can i look?

Comment: check the webserver (apache or nginx) log files and check the error in the log

Comment: have you run vagrant provision?

Comment: @Birdman yes. now i found where is the problem. it is in hosts. i don't know why but browsers ignores hosts

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know why but my hosts file is ignored. Therefore i used just `192.168.10.10` instead `web.app` after 10 hour i fixed the problem. just deleted hosts file and created it again.

Answer (score 0):

First on your homestead.yaml file, make the following changes

```
folders:
    - map: ~/www/web
    to: /home/vagrant/www/web

sites:
    - map: web.app
    to: /home/vagrant/www/web/public
```

Then go to your Homestead folder and do

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

After reloading do

```
vagrant up
```

Then edit the /etc/hosts file and add the following line

```
192.168.10.10  web.app
```

Now you should get laravel homepage when you hit web.app on your browser

Comment: it doesn't helped :/